# Discord.NET 1.0.2 sending voice to voice channel not working

Tags: ffmpeg, voice, discord.net, opus, libsodium

I did everything like the Discord.Net Documentation guide on voice - 
https://discord.foxbot.me/latest/guides/voice/sending-voice.html
and it didn't work the bot just joined the voice channel but it dont make any sound. 
and i have ffmpeg installed in PATH and ffmpeg.exe in my bot Directory along with opus.dll and libsodium.dll so i dont know what is the problem...

```
    public class gil : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("join")]
    public async Task JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel = null)
    {
        // Get the audio channel
        channel = channel ?? (Context.Message.Author as IGuildUser)?.VoiceChannel;
        if (channel == null) { await Context.Message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User must be in a voice channel, or a voice channel must be passed as an argument."); return; }

        // For the next step with transmitting audio, you would want to pass this Audio Client in to a service.
        var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();

        await SendAsync(audioClient,"audio/hello.mp3");
    }

    private Process CreateStream(string path)
    {
        return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
            Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{path}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        });
    }

    private async Task SendAsync(IAudioClient client, string path)
    {
        // Create FFmpeg using the previous example
        using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(path))
        using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
        using (var discord = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
        {
            try { await output.CopyToAsync(discord); }
            finally { await discord.FlushAsync(); }
        }
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: Hi! The issue you're facing here is that the command finishes executing before any audio is sent, it's not a particularly easy fix since it requires quite a few code changes but it's not super complicated. Is this code on GitHub or somewhere else? It would be a lot easier to help if so.

Comment: I have uploaded it for you https://github.com/Saharariel/DiscordBot i couldn't upload ffmpeg.exe because its too big

Comment: Great! I'll have a look at it and give you a hand when I get home.

Comment: Alright thank you very much :)

Comment: Alright I'm home & I can help a bit, do you have Discord by any chance?

Comment: Yes i have my discord is : Saharariel #9434 but i cant speak right now so can you chat?

Comment: 2018.... Please just stop using 1.x. Even the 2.x nightlies are stable.

Comment: @CristianMoraru Would you mind posting, as an answer, what the problem was with this code?

Comment: @rossisdead it's a bit more complicated than that, it wasn't a single factor that caused this to not work, it was a few things. In the end he managed to fix it on his own after looking at some other bots and reading some documentation, so I'm afraid I don't have a simple answer for this question.